# Way to disable git attribute $id$ filter?

Tags: php, git, symfony, phing, gitattributes

I do know it is not a place to discuss product specific problems, yet I try to ask a Git specific question that arouse in a Git GUI product.

The [Phing](http://www.phing.info/) PHP library has the $id$ notation in their source code header and the Git GUI product keeps extending the SHA-1 gitattribute filter onto those files making them appear as modified versions.
Please see the screenshot below how this looks like.

[image]

Can someone disable this built in filter in a gitattribute file? It can be only applied to PHP files.

Comment: You can just use more smart differ, which can ignore changes in `* @version `-matched strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [read Git's documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_tt_ident_tt) and fix your `.gitattributes` accordingly

Git expand %Id% only if if your case met two conditions:

`%Id%` **keyword used** in file **AND** attribute `ident` **is set for a path of type** (of this file) in `.gitattributes`

Comment: According to the found information in the documentations, as long as the command line "official" git shows nothing about this ident, this is the "flaw" of the GUI. Flaw as this cannot be turned off or make it ignore.